# Fill area of DataGrid in WPF window

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF window that contains a DataGrid at the bottom half of the window. When the user first uses the application, the DataGrid will be empty until they start filling in data.

The problem I have is that the area defined for the DataGrid is Greyed out. As more records are added, the new rows replace the grey background. But is there a way to fill the entire DataGrid area with empty rows and columns instead of seeing the grey area? Is there a property for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, datagrid shows only actual items. If you want to make it look better, you can simply change the Background property of DataGrid to a more appropriate value. Like White or Transparent.